# Merge hashes and push values without reseting them

Tags: ruby

The problem is the following:

I have a hash like the one below:

```
hash = {test: [123]}
```

I might need to add to this hash so I use merge!

```
hash.merge!({test2: [345]})
```

which gives me:

```
{test: [123], test2: [345]}
```

but now if I try merging another hash with:

```
{test: [999]}
```

I lose my previous value set on test: and get

```
{test: [999], test2: [345]}
```

rather than what I want:

```
{test: [123, 999], test2: [345]}
```

I know how to partially solve this with a workaround which fails for 1-2 cases... looking to pick someones brain in different ways of solving this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need :

```
# I just considered if values are not array before hand.
hash.merge!(new_hash) { |_, o, n| [o, n].flatten.uniq }
# if you want to keep both old and new inside the array even if
# they are same, do
hash.merge!(new_hash) { |_, o, n| [o, n].flatten }
```

Comment: hash.merge!(new_hash) { |_, o, n| [o, n].flatten.uniq }

Comment: @davidrac liked your idea.

Comment: This one is shorter and I think it may also do the job: h1.merge(h2) { |_, o, n| o | n }

Comment: if either of them is not array.. :/ that's why @davidrac

Comment: Why `uniq`? Did I miss something in the statement of the question?

Comment: @CarySwoveland If `old` and `new` are same.. that's why. Although that's my addition.. OP can ignore the `uniq` part as per the need.

Comment: I'm asking why you assume the OP does not want `{a: [10]}.merge!({a: [10]}) { |_,o,n| o+n } => { a: [10,10] }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland OP [did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602776/merge-hashes-and-push-values-without-reseting-them/30602822?noredirect=1#comment49274152_30602822) like my idea it seems.. But I agree with your assumptions too...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do that:

```
hash = { test: [123] }
arr = [{ test2: [345] }, { test: [999] },
       { test: [123] }, { test2: ['cat','dog'] }]

arr.each_with_object(hash) do|g,h|
   k,v = g.first
   h[k] = (h[k] || []).concat(v)
end
  #=> {:test=>[123, 999, 123], :test2=>[345, "cat", "dog"]}
```

If you do not wish to mutate `hash`:

```
[hash, *arr].each_with_object({}) do|g,h|
   k,v = g.first
   h[k] = (h[k] || []).concat(v)
end
  #=> {:test=>[123, 999, 123], :test2=>[345, "cat", "dog"]} 
hash
  #=> {:test=>[123]}
```

or

```
[hash,*arr].flat_map(&:to_a).
            group_by(&:first).
            values.
            each_with_object({}) do |a,h|
              h[a.first.first] = a.flat_map(&:last)
            end
  #=> {:test=>[123, 999, 123], :test2=>[345, "cat", "dog"]} 
hash
  #=> {:test=>[123]}
```